# inconsistency rendering ** in markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, rendering

Look this question: [firefox: don't save error pages in history](https://superuser.com/questions/40438/firefox-dont-save-error-pages-in-history)

I wrote inside something like this notbold**bold**.notbold.

In javascript it is rendered ok, but in the server, instead the asterisks are shown and the text is not bolded.

Answer (score 4):

This is by design and explained on the blog in the episode entitled, "[Three Markdown Gotchas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/)"

> **1) Markdown’s single biggest flaw is its intra-word emphasis.**
>
> I don’t think anybody writes:
>
> `un*fricking*believable`
>
> often enough to justify making it nearly impossible to talk about tokens with underscores in them:
>
> `some_file_name`
>
> is interpreted as:
>
> `some<em>file</em>name`
>
> It even works across word boundaries:
>
> `file_one and file_two`
>
> becomes:
>
> `file<em>one and file</em> two`
>
> Whenever you’re writing tokens with underscores you have to make absolutely sure you’re in a backtick-delimited code span. The same problem will also nail you on equations like a*b*c, but that seems to pop up less frequently.
>
> Showdown follows the reference implementation on all this, but in WMD I do a little preprocessing to hack the idiocy away: basically I just backslash-escape any underscores or asterisks that might trigger it. It’s a flagrant violation of the standard, but since it’s a pre-pass that should produce identical output with any Markdown processor, I feel justified. Unfortunately my hack did screw up one edge case (which I don’t have in front of me) and there isn’t any way to disable it. Both those things will change in the next release.

Basically, if you want to have i*tal*ics or bold markup in the mi**dd**le of your words, you're going to have to whip out the HTML tags and tag them up that style.

```
Basically, if you want to have i<i>tal</i>ics or bold markup 
in the mi<b>dd</b>le of your words, you're going to have to 
whip out the HTML tags and tag them up that style.
```

Comment: th<b>an</b>k you

Comment: Yeah, but don't count that on working in comments.

Comment: th*an*k you?

Comment: "Unfortunately my hack did screw up one edge case (which I don’t have in front of me) and there isn’t any way to disable it."  -- Yeah, that's why you should use real, consistent markup.  Real, consistent markup doesn't have edge cases.