# What I see is NOT what I get! Why not?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [inconsistency rendering ** in markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21578/inconsistency-rendering-in-markdown)
>   [Preview should match the posted view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view)

Simple. In a Q I wanted to mark part of a path name as italic. This path:

> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

And username must be italic so I get this:

> C:\Documents and Settings*username*\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

Unfortunately, the backslash plus asterisk seems to be considered an escape character thus I need to add another backslash:

> C:\Documents and Settings\*username*\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook

Now the preview looks okay, but I just get it right because I realized the escape sequence. Most users don't. But it gets worse!

When I post it, it gets translated to back slash plus asterisk, not backslash and italic text! That's not what I saw in the preview!

Does this annoy others too? Can someone please fix this? (Btw, even in this post, the Q doesn't look like the thing I typed!)

Comment: The answer lies here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21578/inconsistency-rendering-in-markdown/21579#21579

Comment: Indeed duplicate, although I didn't find it myself. Thus irrelevant. (But provided answer is still okay!)

Comment: The provided answer is **fricking** excellent! *Okay*, pah!

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design and explained on the blog in the episode entitled, "[Three Markdown Gotchas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/)"

> **1) Markdown’s single biggest flaw is its intra-word emphasis.**
>
> I don’t think anybody writes:
>
> `un*fricking*believable`
>
> often enough to justify making it nearly impossible to talk about tokens with underscores in them:
>
> `some_file_name`
>
> is interpreted as:
>
> `some<em>file</em>name`
>
> It even works across word boundaries:
>
> `file_one and file_two`
>
> becomes:
>
> `file<em>one and file</em> two`
>
> Whenever you’re writing tokens with underscores you have to make absolutely sure you’re in a backtick-delimited code span. The same problem will also nail you on equations like a*b*c, but that seems to pop up less frequently.
>
> Showdown follows the reference implementation on all this, but in WMD I do a little preprocessing to hack the idiocy away: basically I just backslash-escape any underscores or asterisks that might trigger it. It’s a flagrant violation of the standard, but since it’s a pre-pass that should produce identical output with any Markdown processor, I feel justified. Unfortunately my hack did screw up one edge case (which I don’t have in front of me) and there isn’t any way to disable it. Both those things will change in the next release.

Basically, if you want to have i*tal*ics or bold markup in the mi**dd**le of your words, you're going to have to whip out the HTML tags and tag them up that style.

```
Basically, if you want to have i<i>tal</i>ics or bold markup 
in the mi<b>dd</b>le of your words, you're going to have to 
whip out the HTML tags and tag them up that style.
```

[alt text http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6717/bolditalichandofgod.png](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6717/bolditalichandofgod.png)

Comment: I recognized that myself, random. And I already upvoted the other one. Ah, who cares...

Comment: Probably could do with some paint magic `*wink* `*wink*

Comment: I already upvoted it. But if you want some paint magic, here we go...

Comment: Alright, let's close out the other one as the dupe and have this as the canonical question/answer.

Comment: I think this misses the point. His problem isn't that markdown is finicky sometimes. His problem is that the preview window doesn't match what we see after we click "post". That at least is a fixable problem.

Comment: No drop shadows?  Worthless.

Comment: @Pesto: You would not recognise art, even if it had hooves and kicked you!