# Problem with markdown and Unicode characters in comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, markdown, unicode

Unicode characters (as well as characters from the extended character-set) don’t work with the markdown in comments.

In a question or answer, when you use Unicode characters (or extended characters for example from code page 1252, etc.) it looks normal—the browser notwithstanding:

`“Foo bar—baz.”` = “Foo bar—baz.” (1252)

`“Foo bar—baz.”` = “Foo bar—baz.” (Unicode)

`"Foo bar—baz."` = "Foo bar—baz." (ASCII)

Now when you throw in markdown (for example italicizing), you get the following:

`“*Foo* bar—**baz**.*”` = “*Foo* bar—**baz**.” (1252)

`“*Foo* bar—**baz**.*”` = “*Foo* bar—**baz**.” (Unicode)

`"*Foo* bar—**baz**.*"` = "*Foo* bar—**baz**." (ASCII)

Okay, it looks fine. But when you do the same thing in a comment, the extended/Unicode characters are not recognized as non-alphanumeric characters/delimiters and prevent the markdown from working correctly.

Another example is spaces. You can use non-breaking or hair-spaces in questions and answers as normal:

`"foo bar baz​blah"` = "foo bar baz​blah" (there’s a zero-space width between baz and blah)

`"*foo* bar **baz**​blah"` = "*foo* bar **baz**​blah" (there’s a zero-space width between baz and blah)

Again, it’s fine, but when you put it in a comment, it breaks the markdown.

(I’ll add a comment with the examples.)

This may be related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28967/problems-with-markdown-in-post-comments), in which case a new system might be needed to handle character-set collation instead of a simple delimiter array.

Comment: `“Foo bar—baz.”` = “Foo bar—baz.” (1252)

`“Foo bar—baz.”` = “Foo bar—baz.” (Unicode)

`"Foo bar—baz."` = "Foo bar—baz." (ASCII)

`“*Foo* bar—**baz**.*”` = “*Foo* bar—**baz**.” (1252)

`“*Foo* bar—**baz**.*”` = “*Foo* bar—**baz**.” (Unicode)

`"*Foo* bar—**baz**.*"` = "*Foo* bar—**baz**." (ASCII)

`"foo bar baz?blah"` = "foo bar baz?blah" (there’s a zero-space width between baz and blah)

`"*foo* bar **baz**?blah"` = "*foo* bar **baz**?blah" (there’s a zero-space width between baz and blah)

(**Err, messy without newline support in comments.**)

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

We are much stricter about which characters are allowed to trigger Markdown in comments to avoid accidental, unwanted Markdown formatting.

Comment: Are there a lot of people accidentally inserting extended and Unicode characters and markdown in comments?