# Handle proper quotation marks in comment Markdown

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Italics markup not working in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64706/italics-markup-not-working-in-comments) 
>   [Problem with markdown and Unicode characters in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96669/problem-with-markdown-and-unicode-characters-in-comments)

Mid-word Markdown like `*long*word` isn't allowed on Stack Exchange. But there seem to be a test to allow things like `"*word*"` to get "*word*" (this also works in comments). In questions and answers it is possible to use proper quotation mark characters, like `“*word*”` (“*word*”). But this doesn't work in comments and chat.

Could the characters `“”‘’` be also added as punctuation characters in comment Markdown?

Comment: @Rick: Thank you for the link, I didn't find that one. Since this a feature-request rather than a bug report is it still a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that distinction.  Just related then.

Comment: Just curious, how exactly do you enter those curly quotes down using a simple US keyboard without memorizing the Alt codes?

Comment: @Chichiray: Simple: I don't use a standard US keyboard layout. Instead I use the [Neo layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Neo) (mostly for the math-related keys, but curly quotes are a nice side-benefit).

Comment: Ah right, a keyboard which is used by only 1% of the SE visitors.

Comment: @Chi That is more than I would have guessed.

Answer (score 1):

When I asked about a similar question ( [Why do bold links syntax in comments work differently than answer text box?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99097/162697) ) about the functioning of markdown in comments, @Jeff mentioned the following:

```
The rules for bold and italic are stricter in comments; this is by design to 
prevent false positives.Remember that comments are a stricter subset of  
markdown, what we call "mini-markdown". See the below link
```

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

I don't know if that helps you but just wanted to let you know. Comments mark down don't work exactly like question and answer in certain cases.

Comment: I know that markdown in comments is restricted. Hence I specifically asked to add the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply *cheat the system* a little, and format it using multiple code-blocks, and surround the ones which are desired to be formatted with said formatting:

`abc`*`def`*`ghi`[`jkl [link]`](http://test.com/)`mno`

Looks like this in the editor: `` abc`_`def`_`ghi`[`jkl [link]`](http://test.com/)`mno ``

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough: I want to write italic text, not code.

Comment: Ah, then this wouldn't help - didn't entirely understand the question, sorry.