# Italics won't work in comments if the closing * is followed by ™

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

In comments, the text `Well, this is a *test*™` gets rendered as-is. The italics isn't applied.

It does work if I use `Well, this is a *test*tm` or `Well, this is a *test* ™`, so it appears to be a unicode problem?

This only happens in comments, not in questions or answers: Well, this is a *test*™

This:

[image]

gets rendered as:

[image]

Comment: It does work when you include the TM in the italic: Well, this is a *test™*

Comment: [Problem with markdown and Unicode characters in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96669/problem-with-markdown-and-unicode-characters-in-comments) apparently this is by-design o_O