# Why intra-word ** highlighting is broken to protect programming_underscore_usage?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, markdown, markdown-rendering

The similar case was discussed here: [inconsistency rendering ** in markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21578/inconsistency-rendering-in-markdown).

Though quick help on formatting proposes to use `_italic_` and `**bold**`, in fact you can use `*italic*` and `__bold__` with the same effect. But when double asterisk is used *inside* the word, one pair of asterisks (or underscores) is not converted to formatting, but is kept as is: it_a_lic, it*a*lic, b__ol__d, b**ol**d.

If I understand correctly the double-asterisk bold highlighting doesn't work inside words to make simpler programming_style_underscore_usage.

Actually my question is because of [my post on RussianSE](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/2512/551), where I tried to indicate difference in stress between two words:

[image: preview rendering],

but after posting I've got:

[image: after posting].

So, I have two questions here:

1. On programming-related sites - why underscore-protection should influence asterisks as well?
2. Can this feature be disabled on non-programming-related sites?

Comment: The intra-word emphasis disabling shouldn't exist anyway, just `use_code_formatting`

Comment: He doesn't want code formatting, @Doorknob. It is not code, it is a word. The proper workaround is to use the HTML tags.

Comment: @CodyGray I've seen the post about the workaround, but the inconsistensy between cyrillic and latin letters still exists.

Comment: @CodyGray That decision was made before SE 2.0, I don't think it's an unreasonable request to disable it on non-programming sites.

Comment: Agreed. That is very strange. I had to test it out for myself, but sure enough you're telling the truth. :-) I suppose it's another bug related to the fact that we use a different parser for the preview window.

Comment: @Cody I meant that (IMHO) the intra-word emphasis disable rule shouldn't exist at all because I don't really see a use for it - name one English word with an underscore in it?

Comment: I don't know, it is tricky to apply the principle of least astonishment here. Emphasis *within* a word seems like a very unusual case to me, and I wouldn't expect characters typed within a word to have a magical effect. But then again, they work *outside* of words, so perhaps there is a consistency argument here? Either way, though, the preview needs to be fixed so that you can see the problem and fix the mistake.

Comment: @Cody `**em**phasis`? Or maybe you want to point out that a user typed `fooTh**r**eBar`? Anyway, anything with underscores in it is probably code

Comment: @Artemix By the way how does that title have anything to do with the question

Comment: Wait I thought the main question was `But why underscore-protection should influence asterisks as well?`

Comment: @Doorknob Initially I was asking about the bug, but while I was writing the question this idea came to my mind and I forgot to write about the bug.

Comment: @CodyGray I changed the title and body to focus on feature-request.

Comment: I see. I find the question confusing as it's currently worded. You're jamming 2 or 3 different things all together, and the lack of context doesn't help matters. I was trying to make it clearer. Your choice.

Comment: `*there is **some** potential ambiguity*  concerning ***nested** highlights*`

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188375/make-the-bold-and-italic-buttons-context-sensitive-for-intra-word-emphasis) for the work around (using <b></b> tags)

Comment: @JanDvorak But why this ambiguity is processed differently between outer-highlighting and in-word-highlighting?

Comment: @Artemix in case of extra-word highlighting, you can safely assume asterisks after a space are opening, and asterisks before a space are closing.

Comment: @JanDvorak The post is about a feature that ignores one level of _ or * highlighting: `a_b_c` is left as a_b_c, `a__b__c` -> a_<i>b</i>_c, a___b___c  -> a_<b>b</b>_c, a____b____c -> a_<b><i>b</i></b>_c. This feature does not target ambiguity you describe, this is purely underscore-protection feature.

Comment: Related: *[Markdown change: Intra-word emphasis now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)*

Answer (score 4):

Implementing different rules for such critical markup between different sites would be confusing as hell.

The HTML fallback will have to suffice.

Comment: This makes very horrible experience on sites that uses Japanese, or upcoming sites that uses Chinese characters, which normally doesn't use spaces.

Comment: Maybe help on markdown should describe this behavior? I see that people find this issue on regular basis and only by searching Meta one can find a way to workaroud the problem.

Comment: intra-word highlighting in a language without space-separated words is something of a different issue, @nhahtdh, and wouldn't necessarily be fixed by this request anyway: what if you wanted a Japanese programming site? I suspect the parser will need to be enhanced to support these languages at some point, but not at the expense of consistency elsewhere.

Comment: This request is now essentially  status-completed rather than declined.

Comment: Completed insofar as it works better on *every* site; still works the same on programming and non-programming sites.