# Cyrillic letter-highlighting differs in preview and in post, while identical for latin characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

I found that the rendering `xxx**yyy**zzz` as `xxx*<i>yyy</i>*zzz` is by-design, but for latin letters it works identical both in preview and after posting. But this is not so for cyrillic letters.

In [this post](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/2512/551) I marked two letters inside a word using double asterisks:

```
(this is like sailors say комп**а**с, while non-sailors say к**о**мпас).
```

In edit preview it is shown as bold:

> [image: preview rendering]

But in the post itself it is shown as italic between asterisks:

> [image: after posting]

Changing double-asterisks to double-underscore yields the same result both for preview and after posting:

> [image]

So this looks like a bug with processing the highlighting of cyrillic characters in preview mode.

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Why intra-word ** highlighting is broken to protect programming_underscore_usage?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192875/196120) post. This post is about bug, linked post is about (1) removing the feature on non-programming sites or (2) different processing of ** and __ highlighting.

Comment: If it not something specific to Russian meta (which I believe is not), it's better to ask such things on Big Meta )))

Comment: @shabunc Looks like this is specific to cyrillic letters. Latin characters are highlighted the same way in preview and after posting. Should I repost it on Big Meta?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Changed both posts - this one is about a bug, the one you linked is feature-request (process ** and __ differently).

Comment: See also: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/120/issues-with-bolding (a bug report from 2(!) years ago).

Comment: This is now fixed per [this post](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/120/issues-with-bolding/1198#1198) on [meta.japanese.SE].

Comment: @senshin So, now it is consistent.