# "Possible Duplicate" post notice links to removed question

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I was just looking at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21578/inconsistency-rendering-in-markdown), which is marked as a "Possible Duplicate" of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view).

The keen observer will note that the latter has been "removed from Meta Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation."

I don't know whether this is a problem on the "exact duplicate" banner, although I'd imagine it is, and it's definitely an edge case, but it seems very odd to be linked from a giant yellow banner that says, in essence, "go read this better question here," and to then have that question deleted for reasons of moderation.

It would be much better to not display that banner when the target question is deleted or, perhaps, remove any back references to a question when it gets deleted. It would really be okay to even have a scheduled script to clean these things up, since I don't think it's a common problem.

The thought also crossed my mind that it should only be hidden from users who can't see deleted content, but realistically I don't imagine any deleted question will be worth linking to.

Comment: See [Auto-flag duplicates of deleted questions for reopening / deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221619/), and the posts linked to that one.

Comment: See also: [“Duplicate of… deleted post”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43724/213963) and associated [linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/43724?lq=1).

Answer (score 3):

Deleted questions can be linked to (usefully) from meta sites as part of a discussion about that post or a bug report.  We wouldn't want to break those links, so any cleanup should be limited to the main site.

That said, it's not clear what auto-cleanup would be appropriate.  If a question is closed as a duplicate and the duplicate target is then deleted, which of the following should we do?

- **Reopen the question, as it's no longer a duplicate.**  If the target is not closed then this may be the right thing to do, but I don't think we want to automatically reopen ex-duplicates that are still not good questions.  Sometimes a question closed as a duplicate should still be closed for some other reason.
- **Delete the dupe; if the original didn't deserve to live, neither does this one.** I think that would be very dangerous; what if the original was removed for being poorly-asked and thus downvoted, and this one is better?
- **Remove the banner but leave the question closed.** Well that's a little confusing; the close reason says "duplicate" but even 10kers can no longer tell of what?  At least with the status quo, people who can see deleted posts can evaluate the situation.
- **Reclose the question for some other reason.** Maybe a new "dead duplicate" closure?  Is it worth whatever the cost of maintaining an extra close type is?  I don't know.

I think it's clear that users, not bots, should decide the fate of these questions.  I can think of two ways to do that:

- **Leave it alone until someone comes across it.** This is the status quo.  A closed question probably doesn't get much attention anyway; when it *does*, the person who comes across it can investigate (if 10k), flag, or raise it on meta or in chat.  The community then figures out what to do.
- **Raise an alert.**  I suggest sending it to the reopen queue with a message like "This question was closed as a duplicate of a question that is no longer present."  Let the reviewers edit, vote to delete, or vote to reopen.  Note that, like posts with close flags, it would enter the queue with no votes.

As for links in places other than duplicate questions (answers, comments, the bodies of other questions), eh, there's not much you can do automatically anyway, so I'd leave 'em alone until somebody notices them.  Unless we're going to do link-checking in general, this should be a small problem.  I've seen more dead links caused by deleted answers (and even comments) than deleted duplicates on some sites.